# Variable isn't storing correctly?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write some code that outputs 3, -6, 9, -12, etc. However, the output is 3, -6 repeatedly.

```
public class Counting {                         
    public static void main (String [] args) { 
        int i;
        int sum  = 3;
        for (i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
            System.out.println(sum);
            sum = (sum + 3) * -1;
            i++;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] again to show your attempt. The answers below don't make sense without it. And actually, they don't make sense with respect to the assignment shown.

Comment: @AndyTurner The OP seems to have edited the question into a completely new one

Comment: Please rollback to your original question, and create a new question called "Trying to find the number of syllables" instead

Comment: You shouldn't have an i++ in the body of the for-loop.

Comment: Please take the time to read the Stack Overflow [help file](https://stackoverflow.com/help), paying special attention to the section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions which will receive good answers. You have quite a few questions which have not been well received. If this trend continues, you are at significant risk of being blocked from posting further questions. Take the advice you have been given and edit your existing questions to fit the standards of the site and maintain those standards when asking in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation is effectively canceling:

> 3 + 3 * -1 = -6

> -6 + 3 * -1 = 3

You can do it easier by using a simple `if/else`:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(3 * i);
    } else {
        System.out.println(-3 * i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
public static void main (String [] args) { 
       int i;
       int sum = 3;
    for (i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
       if(i%2==0) System.out.println(sum);
       else System.out.println(-1*sum);
       sum += 3;
 }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  For(int i=1;I<2500;I++) 
     System.out.print(i%2==0?-3*i:3*i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `sum` is positive before multiplying, you should subtract `3` and if it is negative beforehand, you should add `3`. You could implement this with the ternary operator or with `Integer.signum`. Note that you should not be incrementing `i` inside the `for` loop body, as it will be incremented at the end of each iteration anyway.

See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/sEviTj).

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    int i;
    int sum = 3;
    for (i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
        System.out.println(sum);
        sum = sum * -1 - Integer.signum(sum) * 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the `sum` itself. Change the multiplier `mult`. That should fix it.

```
public static void main(String args[]) { 
    int i;
    int sum  = 3;

    // Add this variable
    int mult = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
        // Use mult while printing
        System.out.println(sum*mult);

        // Keep changing the sum
        sum = (sum + 3);

        // Keep alternating mult every iteration
        mult*=-1;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By making sum = sum + 3 and sum is -6 it will make -6 + 3 = -3 and then *-1
U will have to make a condition to make +3 or -3 in those cases